# Table causing issue

Tags: tables, bibliographies, ltablex

I am trying to make the following table....

```
\begin{landscape}
\pagestyle{empty}
    \small
\setlist[enumerate]{nosep,
                    wide,
                    label=\textbf{\arabic*}.,
                    before = \vspace{-\baselineskip},
                    after  = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                    }
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}lX@{}}
\caption{Taxonomy by focus}
\label{ltable1}
    \\  \toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Literature by focus}
    \\ \midrule
\mc{Focus} &   \mc{Literature} 
    \\
\endfirsthead
\caption{Literature  by focus}
%  \label{tab1}    
\\ \toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{References by focus}
    \\ \midrule
\mc{Focus} &   \mc{Literature}  
    \\
\endhead
    \midrule
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\textit{continue on the next page}}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
\textbf{Financial Crisis \footnote{including credit crisis, liquidity spirals, financial and leverage cycles, early warning indicators and other macroeconomic studies}}  & \citet{myers1977determinants,kaminsky1998leading,Backus:1999,borio2001procyclicality,leigh2003financial,kaminsky2003unholy,rigobon2005effects, schneider2006war,shin2009securitisation,dooley2009transmission,brunnermeier2009fundamental,reinhart2009creditcrisischangeswithtime,borio2009assessing,alessi2009real,diamondrajan2009illiquidity,stein2010securitization,bordo2010creditcrisis,shleifer2010unstable,khandani2010consumer,moosa2010stock,AlessiDetken2011quasi,borio2011implementing,aloui2011global,chudik2011identifying,repullo2011creditcrisis,samarakoon2011stock,min2012dynamic,guo2011markets,neaime2012global,celik2012more,billio2012econometric,gallegati2012wavelet,hoesli2013volatility,drehmann2014creditcrisis,chittedi2014global,Differentfamily-jklhnhe2014macroeconomic,jung2014structural,dungey2015endogenouscrisisdating,Mala:2015,flavin2015role,anderson2015range,elliott2016forecasting,jin2016global,rotta2016analysis, ye2016markov,hemche2016study,hermansen2017economic,bordo2017crisis,cont2017fire,fry2018extremal,fry2019joint,dungey2020crisis} 

    \\  \addlinespace

 \textbf{Systemic Risk \footnote{including micro and macro prudential risk measures}}  & 
 \citet{shaffer1994bank,king1990transmission,king1994volatility,Danielsson&SHin,kashyap2004cyclical,brunnermeier2008market,Diebold:2009,fama2010luck,bank2010bbasel,wagner2010diversification,grubel1971interdependence,kritzman2011principal,hanson2011macroprudential,adrian2011covar,acharya2012capital,Diebold:2012,allen2012asset,khandani2013systemic,patro2013simple,antonakakis2013spillover,elliott2014financial,dungey2014equity,Differentfamily-greenwood2015vulnerable,kim2015spillover,Differentfamily-duarte2015fire,romer2015new,danielsson2016model,adrian2016covar,Differentfamily-chang2016risk,brownlees2016srisk,yang2016interdependence,diebold2017commodity,gonzalez2017re,Differentfamily-brownlees2017back,chiang2017spillover,dungey2018banking,2018_spillover_volatility1,2018spillover2,2018spillover_3,spillover_2018_4,2018spillover,engle2018systemic}

%     \\  \addlinespace
% \textbf{Feedback loop}  &   citet{}

    \\  \addlinespace
\textbf{Contagion}  &   \citet{allen1998optimal,dungey2001contagion,billio2003contagion,gai2010contagion,kazi2011contagion,gai2011complexity,mink2013contagion,dimitriou2013contagion,kazi2014shift,Dimitriou2014contagion,Differentfamily-jobst2014measuring,dungey2014identifying,kenourgios2015contagion,dungey2015contagion,shen2015contagion,jayech2016contagion,lin2015contagion,seth2018financial}

    \\  \addlinespace

\textbf{Financial Network}  &   \citet{allen2000financial,ibragimov2011diversification,acemoglu2012network,diebold2014network,diebold2015financial,Differentfamilywithnetwork-hautsch2014financial,acemoglu2015systemic,DungeyVolkov2017,dungeyvlad2018changing}

    \\  \addlinespace
\textbf{Macroeconomic stress testing} &   citet{}

    \\  \addlinespace 
\textbf{Risk perception/ information transmission} & \citet{diamond1984financial,Diamond:1987,khandani2010consumer,stein2010securitization,diamond2011fear}



\end{tabularx}

    \end{landscape}
```

It was going well, and I was adding citations one by one, no errors at all. suddenly

> ```
> > Runaway argument?
> shaffer1994bank,king1990transmission,king1994volatility,Danielsson\unskip
> ```
>
> \ETC.! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of @for.
>        
>                       \par 
>       l.209 \end{tabularx}
>
> ```
> I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
> to read past where you wanted me to stop.
> I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
> you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.
> ```
>
> And more

```
Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.209 \end{tabularx}

I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
```

And

```
Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.209 \end{tabularx}

I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
```

The table is not compiling. I have no clue why. My preamble

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{subfigmat} % You can either use subfigmat,subfig or subcaption. 
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{morefloats}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{Systemic Crisis Transmission: Visualizing Vulnerability}
\setlength\headheight{15pt}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LO,CE]{chapter \thechapter}
\fancyfoot[CO,RE]{Raisul Islam}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\usepackage{ltablex}
\keepXColumns
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
% \usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
% \addbibresource{ref.bib}



\title{Thesis}
\author{raisul.islam}
\date{February 2020}

\begin{document}

%\maketitle
\input{chapter/titlepage}
\input{chapter/Abstract}
\tableofcontents
\pagestyle{empty}
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\newpage
\input{chapter/Literature Review}
\newpage
\input{chapter/Chapter1}
\newpage
\input{chapter/Chapter2}
\newpage
\input{chapter/Chapter3}
\newpage
\pagestyle{empty} 
\bibliography{ref} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: I suggest that you post a Minimal Working Example.

Comment: (or Not Working in this particular case...)

Comment: The citation kex `Danielsson&SHin` in the `Systemic Risk` risk line seems to be the culprit.

Comment: leandriis thank you so much. yap that fixed it.